# Java JButton - MouseMotionListener ( MouseMoved ) MouseOver Effect

Tags: java, swing, mouseover, jbutton

I'm trying to do the MouseOver effect like it is known in JavaScript in Java for a JButton. I added a MouseMotionListener and it worked. I did want to set 2 other Buttons visible, if my mouse touches the 1st Button. So that works perfectly.. but I don´t know how to handle if the mouse isn´t over the Button. I want to setVisible the Buttons false after the Mouse left the Button

Heres my code:

```
mouseover.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {}
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {

        del.setVisible(true);
        addone.setVisible(true);



    }
```

mouseover is the Button I want to listen to.
del is another Button wich I want to setVisible
addone also

Sry for my not really awesome english :P

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a MouseListener, specifically implementing mouseExited.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html

You may want to use MouseAdapter to avoid being forced to implement all of the methods from MouseListener. MouseAdapter is simply a class that implements the mouse listening interfaces.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want to check `setRolloverIcon()`, `setRolloverSelectedIcon()` methods, instead of using `MouseEvent`.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I want to relize something wich looks like a Dropdown menu.. If my mouse is over an Icon the other buttons should be visible. So setting the RolloverIcon wouldnt be something for me, but thanks. I got it now to the dropdown with the Mouselistener if the mouse touches it, but i cant click the Buttons ... ;o

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `MouseMotionListener`. Use a `MouseListener`, this class has two methods called `mouseEntered()` and `mouseExited()` these should allow you to make the necessary changes as the mouse comes in and out of the button.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) is a brief tutorial on MouseListeners

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer, but doesn´t the mouseEntered() also handles mouseClicked?

Comment: No problem, if you liked my answer you can accept it by clicking the check mark to the left (after your question has been out 15 minutes). Glad I could help!

Comment: MouseListener handles mouseClicked yes. But you can just leave that method body empty!

Comment: I got it now to the dropdown with the Mouselistener if the mouse touches it, but i cant click the Buttons .. I did it like this D; :public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
  
  try {
   Thread.sleep(2500);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  
  
  addone.setVisible(false);
  del.setVisible(false);
  

  
 } I think its because I did let the thread sleep but I dont know another way to pause before it closes again.. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to find a way to use a timer, sleeping the thread will make it so you cant interact with the buttons.